# jQuery / php - Multply forms on page, submit only one

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two forms on my website, and I use jQuery to submit them, to my PHP script.

These are the forms:

```
<form method="post" class="settings-form" id="passwordSettings">
  <label id="npasswordbox" class="infoLabel">New Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="npassword" size="50"  value="" >

  <div class="move"></div> 

  <label id="cnpasswordbox" class="infoLabel">Confirm: </label>
  <input type="password"  name="cnpassword" size="50" value="" >

  <button class="btn" name="passwordSetings" style="margin-left:185px" type="submit">Save </button> 

</form><!-- end form -->
```

And the next:

```
<form method="post" class="settings-form" id="normalSettings">
  <label id="npasswordbox" class="infoLabel">New Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" size="50"  value="" >

  <div class="move"></div> 

  <button class="btn" name="normalSettings" style="margin-left:185px" type="submit">Save </button> 

</form><!-- end form -->
```

Here is the jQuery I have written for these two forms:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#passwordSettings').submit(function(){
        $('#status').hide();
        $.post(
            'index.php?i=a&p=s', 
            $('form#passwordSettings').serialize(),
            function (data) {
                proccessPWData(data);
            }
        );
        return false;    
    });
});

function proccessPWData (data) {
    $('#status').hide().html('');
    if(data=='success'){
        $('form#normalSettings').fadeOut();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});
        $("#status").removeClass();             
        $('#status').addClass('alert alert-success').html('You have successfully changed your personal settings.<br />').slideDown().delay(5000);
        redirect("/account");
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});     
        $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert alert-error').html(data).fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#status').slideUp("slow");
        },7000);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $('form#normalSettings').submit(function(){
        $('#status').hide();
        $.post(
            'index.php?i=a&p=s', 
            $('form#normalSettings').serialize(),
            function (data) {
                proccessData(data);
            }
        );
        return false;    
    });
});

function proccessData (data) {
    $('#status').hide().html('');
    if(data=='success'){
        $('form#normalSettings').fadeOut();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});
        $("#status").removeClass();             
        $('#status').addClass('alert alert-success').html('You have successfully changed your personal settings.<br />').slideDown().delay(5000);
        redirect("/account");
    }
    else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});     
        $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert alert-error').html(data).fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#status').slideUp("slow");
        },7000);
    }
}
```

And then the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['normalSettings']))
{
    $username = inputFilter($_POST['username']);
    if(!$username){
        $error ="no username";
    }
    if(!$error){
        echo "success!";
    }
} 

if(isset($_POST['passwordSettings']))
{
    $password = inputFilter($_POST['npassword']);
    if(!$username){
        $error ="no pw";
    }
    if(!$error){
        echo "success!";
    }
}
```

My problem is, that whenever I submit one of these forms, I see the form with my $error in the #status div.

**How can I have multiply forms on one page, but submit the correct ones?**

Comment: Try using input type="submit" for your submit buttons. Then it will only submit the form it is within.

Comment: Can you please make an example? Not quite sure what you mean :-)

Comment: which error you see in status div? no pw or no name?

Comment: I just see the whole form inside the status div

Comment: check my answer ı think its solution of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('form#passwordSettings').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action (in this case, submitting the form)
        $('#status').hide();
        $.post(
            'index.php?i=a&p=s', 
            $('form#passwordSettings').serialize(),
            function (data) {
                proccessPWData(data);
            }
        );
        return false;    
    });
});
```

or you could just give an hidden input-field with it

```
<input type="hidden" name="_normalSettings">
```

and check in your PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['_normalSettings']) // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just answer to your question: "How can I have multiple forms on one page, but submit the correct ones?"

I have many dynamically generated forms on a single page and I send them to process file one by one. This is one form simplified:

```
<form name="form" id="form">
<!--form fields
hidden field could be used to trigger wanted process in the process file
-->
<input type="hidden" name="secret_process_id" value="1" />
<a class="button_ajax">Send form</a> 
</form>

<div id="process_msg<?php echo $id; ?>"></div>
```

And here's the form submit function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit_ajax').click(function() { //serializes the parent form
    //alert($(this).serialize());
    dataString = $(this).parent().serialize();

    //if you want to echo some message right below the processed form
    var id = /id=\d+/.exec(dataString);
    var id = /\d+/.exec(id);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '_process.php?ajax=1', //some or none parameters
      data: dataString,
      dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          $('#process_msg' + id).fadeIn(400);
          $('#process_msg' + id).html(data);
        }

     }); //end of $.ajax

return false;

  });
});
```

All you need is a process file/function and you are ready to go. Works just fine with one or dozens of forms. There you can do something like this:

```
if ($_POST['secret_process_id']==1){
  //do something
}

if ($_POST['secret_process_id']==2){
  //do something else
}

//etc.
```